# Powershell .NET System.IO.Compression to C# .NET Conversion

Tags: c#, powershell, unzip, file-search

I have the following which works correctly in powershell was wondering how to do the same thing in C#. I need to find the .zip files and one by one unzip them to a temporary location search through the contents, list file if found then remove temp file move on to the next.

My question is; What would be the corresponding C# methods to be able to accomplish the unzip, file search and delete functionalities?

```
function Lookin-Zips() {
    param ($SearchPattern);
    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($archivePath);
    try {
        # enumerate all entries in the archive, which includes both files and directories
        foreach($archiveEntry in $archive.Entries) {
            # if the entry is not a directory (which ends with /)
            if($archiveEntry.FullName -notmatch '/$') {
                # get temporary file -- note that this will also create the file
                $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
                try {
                    # extract to file system
                    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($archiveEntry, $tempFile, $true);

                    # create PowerShell backslash-friendly path from ZIP path with forward slashes
                    $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName = $archiveEntry.FullName.Replace('/', '\');
                    # run selection
                    Get-ChildItem $tempFile | Select-String -pattern "$SearchPattern" | Select-Object @{Name="Filename";Expression={$windowsStyleArchiveEntryName}}, @{Name="Path";Expression={Join-Path $archivePath (Split-Path $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName -Parent)}}, Matches, LineNumber
                }
                finally {
                    Remove-Item $tempFile;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    finally {
        # release archive object to prevent leaking resources
        $archive.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is how you unzip your files in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

[And you can use GetFiles method to list the matching file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern
)
```

And last you can use [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) to delete files and directories.